# c# out causing a no overload for method error?

Tags: c#, guid, out

I am new to c# and a little confused about how the out parameter modifier works.

I have this function

```
public static void GuidUnsmash(string smashed, out Guid first, out Guid second)
{
    if (smashed.Length != 64)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    string firstGuid = smashed.Substring(0, 32);
    string secondGuid = smashed.Substring(32, 32);

    first = new System.Guid(firstGuid);
    second = new System.Guid(secondGuid);
}
```

which im trying to call using this

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Pending(string pendingticket)
{
    // CAR-AAR built with PersonId and MonerisID in ticket, this was overkill, just needed the MonerisID
    GuidHelpers.GuidUnsmash(pendingticket, out Guid personId, out Guid monerisId); //this is the line that has the error
    var preload = await MonerisApplicationRepository.PrepareTransactionForMonerisPreload(monerisId);
    var preloadResponse = await MonerisRepository.PostPreloadTransactionRequest(preload);
    var persistPreload = await MonerisApplicationRepository.PersistMonerisPreloadTransactionResponse(monerisId, preloadResponse);

    var transactionRequest = preloadResponse.ToMonerisPreAuthorization();

    //var viewPendingRequest = new MonerisPendingPreloadTransaction(transactionRequest, preload);

    // View redirects to Moneris with autosubmit to begin preauthorization process.
    return View(transactionRequest);
}
```

However i am getting an error that says that there is no overload method for GuidUnsmash. Which is confusing me because they both have the same amount of parameters.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem. Make sure you include the *exact* error message.

Comment: @RufusL @Christopher You can inline `out` variable declarations in a method call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables

Comment: Any time you're “getting an error” you need to tell us what the error is.

Comment: If the error you are getting is a compilation error saying 'not all out variables were assigned to' , it is because you have a code path that will not set any values for your out parameters, in this case the throw exception.

Comment: You method compiles and is callable. http://www.ideone.com/5UNthu The error is caused by code you didn't show in your question.

Comment: When describing a specific error or exception, please *cut and paste* the actual error message as it is. Paraphrasing the error yourself can cause a lot of confusion, and the original error message is usually searchable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, parameters used in function calls are "passed-by-value". The other option is for parameters to be passed-by-reference.

Keyword `ref` forces a parameter to be passed-by-reference. But that does not mean the function will actually *do* anything with the variable. It may or it may not.

Keyword `out` forces a parameter to be passed-by-reference and also that the value **has** to be assigned in the function. This can have ramifications for stuff like `readonly` variables which need a assignment. And so the caller is aware the value will not stay the same.

Keyword [in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier) is relatively new syntax, related to 'ref' and 'out'. It forces a parameter to be passed-by-reference but also prevents any reassignment of the value (like a inverted `out`). However I am somewhat unsure why you would use it.

In langauges that use naked pointers, usually naked pointer is used instead of `ref`. And there are no `in` or `out` keywords.

**As for overloading:**

> The `in`, `ref`, and `out` keywords are not considered part of the
>   method signature for the purpose of overload resolution. Therefore,
>   methods cannot be overloaded if the only difference is that one method
>   takes a `ref` or `in` argument and the other takes an `out` argument.

Which means the error make no real sense.

So that leaves one hard-to-debug issue: the code is so broken somewhere before or between those two code piece, the compiler has issues even still telling you where the error is.

Comment: It is a valid function call. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables

Comment: @dee-see Ah. Okay, fixed

Comment: the call is valid, you can declare out variables inline.

Comment: @Nandun: You were ninjad by about 2 minutes. And 30 seconds by my edit.

Comment: your out vs ref was great info.

Comment: I'm betting there's another `GuidUnsmash` somewhere that's causing the error.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I believe you would use `in` for performance reasons. If you have a large, read-only value type you could pass it using the `in` parameter to avoid making a copy and also employ the compiler in making sure no changes were made.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson: That optimsiation level is usually something I would leave to the JiT, but I found a reason I think: In does require that the variable is initialized. So I would say the uses are around those short null-check syntax.